# Restrict file input type control to select only text files

Tags: html

The value `text/*` for the `accept` on the `input` element of type `file` does not restrict the selection in the **Open** file dialog to only text files, as it does for other types.

The dialog still shows ***.*** as the file filter.

```
<input type = "file" accept = "text/*" />
```

[image]

```
<input type = "file" accept = "image/*" />
```

[image]

If I do provide specific filters for text files (e.g. `text/plain, text/html`, I see the dialog restricted to those types, but not for the `text/*` filter.

How do I make it restrict its file filter to only text files?

**Note:** Please note that I have already got code to ensure I am not reading files that I want to filter out. I am only concerned with the file filter displayed in the **Open** dialog box in response to the value of the `accept` attribute on the input element.

Comment: Disabling the capability to select all files is already outside the scope of the browser. You can't prevent the browser from offering the "All Files" options.

Comment: Have you tried using `<input type="file" accept="*.txt">` for text files?

Comment: working fine on chrome browser but not working firefox

Comment: @acesmndr that input usually works, but in few client browsers it sometimes will accept other type of file too...for example it will include .csv files in chrome, or docx in safari

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this on various browsers and it appears to be a bug in that it differs from what is mentioned in the specification, and at best a difference in implementation across various browsers. Here are the behaviors for popular browsers.

Chrome and Opera display all types of text files in the file filter.

**Chrome**

[image]

**Opera**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

And just with every other feature, IE and Edge go their own way. They have their own, weird behavior. They display something like this:

**Internet Explorer**

[image]

**Microsoft Edge**

[image]